# Using core-dropdown to select multiple items

Tags: polymer, core-elements

When a user clicks in a report button, they should be able to select one or more types of issues. I'm trying something like this:

```
<core-icon-button icon="report" on-tap="{{ openDropdown }}">
   <core-dropdown>
      <core-selector valueattr="label" multi>
         <core-item label="Type 1"></core-item>
         <core-item label="Type 2"></core-item>
         <core-item label="Type 3"></core-item>
      </core-selector>
      <button on-tap="{{ reportIssue }}">Report</button>
   </core-dropdown>
</core-icon-button>
```

But when I select any item the dropdown closes. My expected behaviour would be to close the dropdown only after `reportIssue` is called.

Is what I'm trying to do possible with `core-dropdown` (or any other core element) or should I build a custom element for this? Feels like a waste since almost all the behaviour I need is provided already by `core-dropdown`.

**EDIT:** The problem seems to be that I had `core-dropdown` inside `core-icon-button`. After I changed that everything works as expected. :)

Comment: use core-selector.. you can check the demo [https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-selector/demo.html]

Answer (score 0):

Try `closeAttribute` or `closeSelector`. See `core-overlay` documentation