# How to use paper-dropdown-menu to select multiple items?

Tags: polymer, dart-polymer, paper-elements

Is there a way use paper-dropdown-menu to let the user select multiple items when the dropdown opens and then close it by tapping outside of it?  Currently, the dropdown closes each time one item is tapped. I think this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125583/using-core-dropdown-to-select-multiple-items) one, but I do not understand how to proceed with the solution mentioned there.  Thanks!

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="General">
  <paper-dropdown class = "dropdown">
     <core-menu class = "menu"  multi>
        <paper-item name = "item1">item1</paper-item>
        <paper-item name = "item2">item2</paper-item>
        <paper-item name = "item3">item3</paper-item>
     </core-menu>
  </paper-dropdown>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: There is a hack here that may help you get what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268725/prevent-menu-close-on-multi-select-paper-dropdown-menu-polymer-1-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think paper-dropdown-menu/ core-dropdown-menu isn't for your case. Because they always toggle state. But you can open menu manually as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125583/using-core-dropdown-to-select-multiple-items) (openDropdown function)

Comment: Thank you!  i will implement something along the lines of that example then.